Having a second java version available
Running MacOS 12 on Intel hardware. Current java runtime is Java 8:
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_341-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.341-b10, mixed mode)

and this is /usr/bin/java.
For performance measurements, I would like to have also a higher Java version available; currently I'm only interested in JRE, not JDK. I want to see whether the same Java Byte code exhibits different timing und different JRE versions (perhaps due to different garbage collectors?).
My plan was to install a higher Java in, say, $HOME/java. When I run my application, I can explicitly specify the absolute path to the java I want to run. However I don't know how to do this. This is how I proceeded:

I googled for the possibility to download JRE, but didn't find anything.
I then found the site http://java.oracle.com/ and it offers only the SDK versions. Well, it's overkill, but then let's download the whole SDK. This should also include the runtime.
I downloaded https://download.oracle.com/java/21/latest/jdk-21_macos-x64_bin.dmg
I double-clicked the DMG and found inside a file JDK 21.0.4.pkg, which seems to be the installer.
Executing the installer, I found that there are written menu entries Instruction, Destination select, Installation type, Installation, but I can not go to the item Destination select. The installation always proceeds directly to Installation type, and offers only the "standard installation" (which most likely means replacing my current Java by the new one).

So I wonder what I can do to have two Javas on my Mac? If I could get from somewhere just the binaries in a zip file, I could unpack them into a directory of my liking ....

Not only is this possible, but there is a tool asdf to help you manage the environment setup needed to have both (or more) installed and which is the default for any project or point in time.

https://asdf-vm.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asdf-vm

If you decide to run the installs yourself, here is the best resource I’ve seen for managing this, although many of the answers are a bit dated so make a backup and we can always take a follow,on question should you need help over any bumps due to new OS and new Java versions.

If I understand it correctly, asdf sets the Java version kind of globally. I want to have several shells in parallel, each which its own Java version. That's why I fiddle with the PATH.

Yes - my understanding matches yours. You would need to call asdf in each shell to promote the version you want. Just depends which effort aligns with your setting things manually.

While I don't know why the Java installer does not permit to set the destination, I found an alternative way to achieve it:
On the same page where I can download the DMG file, there is also a TAR file (jdk-21_macos-x64_bin.tar.gz), which I can download and unpack.
